# how to pass conditional argument as command in kubernetes with helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have to run a command when my pod start in `kubernetes` which takes some argument but those argument are conditional. How to set those values. My configuration looks like

```
#file: values.yaml
arguments:
  debug: false
  values: 16 # this is not necessarily set
```

```
#deployment command section looks like
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "./my_app.sh" ]
args:
    - {{ -f .Values.arguments.debug }}
    - {{ -v .Values.arguments.values}}
```

But it seems to not accepting argument. Is this incorrect way. How can I pass multiple argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm uses the [Go `text/template` language](https://godoc.org/text/template) with a number of extensions; the Helm [Chart Template Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) has quite a few examples.

In particular the templating language includes an `if`...`else`...`end` construct.  You can use this like:

```yaml
args:
  - -f
  - {{ quote .Values.arguments.debug }}
{{- if .Values.arguments.values }}
  - -v
  - {{ quote .Values.arguments.values}}
{{- end }}
```

Note that the `-f` and `-v` text are outside the template curly braces, and I've split them out into separate items in the argument list.  In the last part there's a test if the `values` option is set, and the `-v` option isn't emitted if it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @David Maze but when I am using the args apparently it is not taking argument cause I have made a check which gives message `Missing mandatory argument -f` while it works fine when I pass argument  in `command` tag

Comment: In the question you wrap the command in `/bin/bash -c`.  That requires you to pack the entire command into a single argument and apply shell escaping; you can still use Helm templating, including the `{{ if }}` conditional, within that string.  If the command is just a simple word as you show, changing it to `command: ["./my_app.sh"]` without the `sh -c` wrapper will make it honor `args:`.